# How to open a particular tab inside a modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, bootstrap-modal

I have 2 buttons and each is responsible for opening a modal, however, this modal has 2 tabs for signup and sign in. I want that if a user clicks on signup button then after the modal opens the signup tab should be active and if a user clicks on sign in button then after the modal opens the sign in tab should be active

The code of the button is

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg">SIGN UP</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg_two">SIGN IN</button>
```

The code of modal is

```
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" >
                    <li class="nav-item col ">
                        <a class="nav-link active" href="#signup" data-toggle="tab" >Sign up</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item col ">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#signin" data-toggle="tab" >Sign in</a>
                    </li> 
                </ul>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">
                            <div class="tab-content">
                                <div class="tab-pane active" id="signup">
                                    signup box
                                </div>
                                <div class="tab-pane" id="signin">
                                    signin box                  
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col" id="social" >
                            Content
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Can anyone please tell me how to do this

Comment: shown.bs.modal event trigger after model is opened.

Comment: @sammy Did you solve this, did my answer help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to do it with Javascript.  Here's one way.  [Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dont_panic/jhj59gya/).

**First**, get rid of the `data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg"` on both buttons.  You'll need to run your tab-targeting Javascript when you open the modal, and you can easily do that if you manually open the modal using [the modal show method](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals-methods), rather than via the `data` attributes.

**Next**, in their place, add something to each button to identify which tab it targets - for eg a `data` attribute, with the `id` of your tabs:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-tab="signup">SIGN UP</button>
```

**Last**, add some Javascript to do the work:

```
// Add an event handler to fire when our buttons are clicked
$('button').on('click', function() {
    // Find which button was clicked, so we know which tab to target
    var tabTarget = $(this).data('tab');

    // Manually show the modal, since we are not doing it via data-toggle now
    $('.bd-example-modal-lg').modal('show');

    // Now show the selected tab
    $('.nav-tabs a[href="#' + tabTarget + '"]').tab('show');
});
```

[Note that as the docs describe](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#tabs-methods), you target the tab with the `a` link which opens it, not the `div` of the tab itself.